# How to select/get object elements' (array of objects) keys based on value of an element in an object in the aforementioned array in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following input:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "subkey1": [
      {
        "filterkey1": "value1",
        "filterkey2": "value2"
      },
      {
        "filterkey1": "value3",
        "filterkey2": "value4"
      }
    ],
    "subkey2": [
      {
        "filterkey1": "value5",
        "filterkey2": "value6"
      },
      {
        "filterkey1": "value7",
        "filterkey2": "value8"
      }
    ],
    "subkey3": [
      {
        "filterkey1": "value1",
        "filterkey2": "value6"
      },
      {
        "filterkey1": "value9",
        "filterkey2": "value4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "key2": {
  }
}
```

I want to get the key of the arrays that has an object which has `"value1"` for key: `"filterkey1"`. So in this case the output must be:

```
["subkey1", "subkey3"]
```

**All the elements I care about are in "key1" object.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get *subkey*s using `keys_unsorted`, and check if their values have `filterkey1: "value1"` pair using `any`:

```
.key1 | [
    keys_unsorted[] as $k
    | if any(.[$k][]; .filterkey1=="value1")
    then $k 
    else empty end
]
```